# why are picard groups called picard groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, picard-scheme

I am looking for an origin of the picard groups. Unfortunately I cann't find a reference where this is mentionned. Does anybody know where the name comes from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a (translated) quote from G. Castelnuovo, "Sur les intègrales de différentielles totales appartenant à une surface irrégulaière", Comptes rendus hebdomadaires des séances de l'Acadeémie des sciences, Paris. **140**, 23 Jan 1905. pp. 220-222:

> *out of respect for Picard's profound research on
>   surfaces admitting a group of birational automorphisms, [he] proposes calling the variety $P$ (and [a certain] group $G_d$) the Picard variety (and Picard group) associated to the surface $X$.*

I have found this in Kleiman's "The Picard scheme", which contains some further historical remarks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_group) "The name is in honor of Émile Picard's theories, in particular of divisors on algebraic surfaces." I would assume one of the references on the page probably contains what you want.

Comment: Also from Wikipedia: "He [Emile Picard] also introduced the Picard group in the theory of algebraic surfaces, which describes the classes of algebraic curves on the surface modulo linear equivalence."